# Whatsapp templates management & approval through the Twilio API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

As per `Whatsapp` [policies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/messages/) and `Twilio` [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#whatsapp-message-templates-overview), the business initiated conversations require the pre-approved message templates. The [Whatsapp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/) provides a programmatic way to maintain and approve such templates.

Is there an appropriate API endpoint on the `Twilio` side for the programmatic `Whatsapp`'s templates management? I haven't found anything except the manual template submission using the [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#creating-message-templates-and-submitting-them-for-approval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Messaging Content API was announced at SIGNAL 2021](https://www.twilio.com/blog/what-you-missed-from-messaging-at-signal-2021) and will allow you to register and use templates for multiple services through an API. The Content API is currently in pilot and you can [request access to the pilot using the form here](https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1).

Answer (score -1):

The messaging content API will allow you to use the Whatsapp template.